# getDeclaredFields for an abstract class for testing

Tags: java, private, abstract, protected

Can someone please explain to me how can I get private fields of an abstract class while unit testing?
It can be divided to two:

1. how to create the class variable.
2. how to get the private fields from it for testings.

For example:

```
public abstract class pclass{
    private int toCheck = 0;

    public void change(){
        toCheck++;
    }
}
```

How toCheck the change method (useful for a more complex method of course...) ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the answer to your second question is in your title: `getDeclaredFields()`.

Comment: Why you need testing private fields? The general recommendation is not test private fields/methods.

http://lassekoskela.com/thoughts/24/test-everything-but-not-private-methods/

Answer (score 0):

For a `void` method, you generally need to test side effects. In your case, there has to be another method that enables you to access that side effect (otherwise the `change` method is useless). That's what you need to test.

If you have a real life example in mind it would properly help to share it.

An alternative is to make the field package private and flag it - if you use guava:

```
@VisibleForTesting int toCheck = 0;
```